# How many halachot are detailed in the Mishneh Torah?

Tags: number, jewish-books, rambam, statistics, mishneh-torah

How many halachot are detailed in the Mishneh Torah?

To clarify, I am interested in the counting of the author's (i.e. if the Mishneh Torah details two rules under one halacha that counts as one and not two).

Comment: Note that there are differing numbering schemes for _Mishne Tora_. But I guess any answer can say which scheme it's using.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is only one numbering scheme. Though he uses the word Halachah to refer to both a group of halachot, and individual halachot.  I am curious in the total number of indidvidual ones.

Comment: There seem to be at least two numbering schemes. The only way I know this is from the Mechon Mamre site, which breaks up the _Mishne Tora_ two ways. [E.g.](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3507.htm)

Comment: This is one of a group of similar questions: [_mitzvos_](http://yodeya.com/q/34253), [_Mishna_](http://yodeya.com/q/34224), [_Y'rushalmi_](http://yodeya.com/q/34254), [_Bavli_](http://yodeya.com/q/34252), [_Mishne Tora_](http://yodeya.com/q/34248), [_Shulchan Aruch_](http://yodeya.com/q/34249), [_Mishna B'rura_](http://yodeya.com/q/34251),  [_Yalkut Yosef_](http://yodeya.com/q/34250)

Comment: Indeed mechon-mamre explains that, although _fully confident_ that the versions of texts they have based upon manuscripts are correct, they include the conventional numbering in brackets. See the bottom of [this page](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/aboutpsq.htm).

Comment: This seems off-topic

Comment: @msh210 I would imagine there are more than 2 numbering schemes though based on different manuscripts?

Comment: @msh210 Are there multiple numbering schemes "of the author's"? Seems unlikely unless he changed his mind between editions, and that seems likely to be an incredibly small number of cases.

Comment: @DoubleAA He changed his mind in lots of places between editions of the Peirush Hamishnayot.

Comment: @hesh I think you mean between the peirush hamishna and the mishne torah not between editions of the same work, and moreover those are differences in rulings not in paragraph layout. Many changes of law don't need new paragraph layouts

Comment: @DoubleAA yes between the peirush hamishnayot and the mishnah torah, but also between editions of the peirush hamishnayot.  Check R' Qafih's footnotes.  I remember seeing at least one place where he changed it 3 or 4 times.  But yes I agree, paragraph breaks are less likely to change.

Comment: @hesh as I said above, it's bound to lead to an incredibly small number from of relevant cases

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/0.htm):

**TL;DR**

**TOTAL** - 16,818 (+ 104)

1. **Hamada`** - 725
2. **Ahavah** - 730 (+ 63)
3. **Zemanim** - 1,738 (+ 41)
4. **Nashim** - 1,207
5. **Qedushah** - 1,140
6. **Hafla'ah** - 820
7. **Zera`im** - 1,582
8. **`Avodah** - 1,537
9. **Haqorbanot** - 651
10. **Taharah** - 2,317
11. **Nezaqim** - 993
12. **Qinyan** - 1,191
13. **Mishpattim** - 1,141
14. **Shofettim** - 1,046

---

1. **Hamada`** - 725

   - Yesode'i HaTorah - 140
   - De`ot - 130
   - Talmud Torah - 107
   - `Avodah Zarah Wehuqot Hagoyim - 218
   - Teshuvah - 130
2. **Ahavah** - 730 (+ 63)

   - Qer'iat Shema` - 58
   - Tefillah U'birkat Kohanim - 253
   - Tefillin U'mezuzah Wesefer Torah - 162
   - Zizit - 40
   - Berakhot - 180
   - Milah - 37
   - (Seder Hatefillah - 63)
3. **Zemanim** - 1,738 (+ 41)

   - Shabbat - 665
   - `E'iruvin - 165
   - Shevitat `Asor - 28
   - Shevitat Yom Tov - 178
   - Hamez U'mazah - 122 (+ 41)

     - (Nusah Hahaggadah - 41)
   - Shofar Wesukkah Welulav - 132
   - Sheqalim - 49
   - Qiddush Hahodesh - 252
   - Ta`aniyot - 84
   - Megillah Wehanukkah - 63
4. **Nashim** - 1,207

   - Ishut - 581
   - Girushin - 323
   - Yibum Wehalizah - 189
   - Ne`arah Betulah - 42
   - Sottah - 72
5. **Qedushah** - 1,140

   - Issure'i Bi'ah - 499
   - Ma'akhalot Assurot - 408
   - Shehittah - 233
6. **Hafla'ah** - 820

   - Shevu`ot - 198
   - Nedarim - 252
   - Nezirut - 193
   - Arakhim U'heramim - 177
7. **Zera`im** - 1,582

   - Kilayim - 181
   - Matenot `Aniyim - 194
   - Terumot - 332
   - Ma`aser - 241
   - Ma`aser Sheni Wenetta` Reva`i - 190
   - Bikkurim `Im She'ar Matenot Kehunah She'bagevulin - 218
   - Shemittah Weyovel - 226
8. **`Avodah** - 1,537

   - Be'it Habehirah - 132
   - Kele'i Hamiqdash Weha`ovdim Bo - 156
   - Bi'at Hamiqdash - 140
   - Issure'i Mizbe'ah - 101
   - Ma`aseh Haqorbanot - 315
   - Temidin U'mussafin - 172
   - Pessule'i Hamuqdashin - 310
   - `Avodat Yom Hakippurim - 86
   - Me`ilah - 125
9. **Haqorbanot** - 651

   - Qorban Pessah - 149
   - Hagigah - 40
   - Bekhorot - 123
   - Shegagot - 212
   - Mehussre'i Kapparah - 71
   - Temurah - 56
10. **Taharah** - 2,317

    - Tum'at Met - 385
    - Parah Adumah - 218
    - Tum'at Zara`at - 250
    - Mettame'i Mishkav U'moshav - 196
    - She'ar Avot Hatum'ot - 331
    - Tum'at Okhalin - 284
    - Kelim - 470
    - Miqwot - 183
11. **Nezaqim** - 993

    - Nizqe'i Mamon - 238
    - Genevah - 137
    - Gezelah Wa'avedah - 301
    - Hovel U'maziq - 138
    - Roze'ah U'shmirat Nefesh - 179
12. **Qinyan** - 1,191

    - Mekhirah - 455
    - Zekhiyah U'matanah - 208
    - Shekhenim - 209
    - Sheluhin U'shutafin - 160
    - `Avadim - 159
13. **Mishpattim** - 1,141

    - Sekhirut - 193
    - She'elah U'fiqadon - 103
    - Malweh Weloweh - 437
    - To`en Wenitt`an - 258
    - Nehalot - 150
14. **Shofettim** - 1,046

    - Sanhedrin Weha`unshin Hamessurin Lahem - 327
    - `Edut - 253
    - Mamrim - 103
    - Evel - 194
    - Melakhim U'milhamot - 169

Comment: Here is the JavaScript I'm using on Mechon Mamre to extract the number of laws per topic: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("b")).filter(function (n) { return n.innerHTML.match("^.{1,2},.{1,2}$") !== null; }).length;`

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to calculate the number of halachot in Mishneh Torah is to use the URLs in [the version on Hebrewbooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam). Each halacha has a unique URL ending in a number, with the first halacha starting with the number 1. Each URL increases by one from the previous URL. Thus, [the URL of the very last halacha](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=15024) in Mishneh Torah contains the total number of halachot. In this case we can see that it comes out to 15,024 halachot.

Of course, as [R. Yosef Qafih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih) already noted in the introduction to his edition of Mishneh Torah, there are differences in the numbering of the halachot between different versions:

> הנוסח הוא על פי כתבי היד וכך גם חלוקת ההלכות נעשתה על פי רוב כתבי היד
>   וקטעי כתבי היד שברשותי והואיל והספרות התורתית העולמית מציינים בספריהם
>   מספרי ההלכות כפי שמופיע בדפוסים לא יכולתי להתעלם מהם לגמרי כדי שלא
>   להקשות על המעיין למצוא דברי חפץ לפיכך עשיתי את המספרים אשר על פי כתבי
>   היד תוך סוגרים מרובעים [ב] ומספר ההלכות על פי הדפוסים תוך סוגרים
>   עגולים (א) ובכך נראה לי שיצאנו ידי חובת הכל
>
> Just as the text is presented according to the manuscripts, the
>   division of the halachot is presented according to the majority of the
>   manuscripts and fragments of manuscripts in my possession. Since Torah
>   literature around the world quotes from the previously printed texts,
>   I could not ignore them entirely, so that the reader can find what he
>   is looking for without difficulty. Therefore I placed the section
>   numbers from the manuscripts in brackets and the section numbers from
>   the printed texts in parentheses, in an effort to oblige everyone. ([Bohnen translation](https://www.mhcny.org/pdf/Introduction%20to%20Mishneh%20Torah.pdf))

As such, there is not necessarily one precise answer to how many halachot there are; the number might vary based on edition/manuscript. Indeed, the number presented here is different from the number presented in [the other answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83382/13438) which used a different (probably more faithful to the original) source.

Here is the breakdown by Sefer:

### Hamada

1-457

Total: 457 halachot

### Ahavah

458-1154

Total: 697 halachot

### Zemanim

1155-2852

Total: 1,698 halachot

### Nashim

2853-4037

Total: 1,185 halachot

### Kedusha

4038-5254

Total: 1,217 halachot

### Hafla'ah

5255-6062

Total: 808 halachot

### Zeraim

6063-7656

Total: 1,594 halachot

### Avodah

7657-9188

Total: 1,532 halachot

### Hakorbanot

9189-9697

Total: 508 halachot

### Tahara

9698-11505

Total: 1,808 halachot

### Nezikin

11506-12446

Total: 941 halachot

### Kinyan

12445-13430

Total: 985

### Mishpatim

13431-14219

Total: 789 halachot

### Shoftim

14220-15024

Total: 805 halachot

Comment: I think "מספרי ההלכות כפי שמופיע בדפוסים" is "_misp're..._". (You translated it as "_misifre..._".)

Comment: @msh210 Admittedly, it is not my translation, and you are probably correct that the word in question is "*misp're*" rather than "*misifre*". However, I'm not sure that the translator disagrees with you. The Hebrew anyway refers to the previously printed texts with the words כפי שמופיע בדפוסים, so it might just be that it's not a precise word-for-word translation and he left out מספרי ההלכות.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I hadn't realized you'd cited the translation as not your own.

Comment: @msh210 Your point is valid regardless of whose translation it is.