# How many Chapters are in the Mishneh Torah?

Tags: number, words, jewish-books, rambam, aleph-bet-letters

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34248/759) addresses how many halachos there are in Mishneh Torah.

How many chapters are in Mishenh Torah? There is a program to do a chapter of Rambam a day and I am interested to know in how many days  till I finish.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and not about Judaism.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, the subject of the question, the Mishneh Torah, is, without question, within the realm of Judaism. I don't particularly like this question, in that it asks for a bunch of work with no apparent motivation, but I fail to see how it could be classified as off-topic.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I concede to your superior experience. IMHO The question "How many" asked about any Judaic book constitutes a question within the realm of Judaism - but not about Judaism.

Comment: @IsaacMoses See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44362/kitzur-shulchan-aruch-statistics

Comment: @user6781 I assume you refer to my comment to Isaac Moses. My view was that your "How many" questions are off-topic because they are about statistics. Isaac Moses does not agree with me. So I wanted to point out your latest "How many" question to him. I would like your questions more if you could explain what significance you would find in the answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16345/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-user6781).

Comment: It will take 3 years if you study 1 chapter per day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly 1000 chapters.  [This blog post on Giluy Milta B'alma](http://imhm.blogspot.com/2008/02/ezra-chwat-rambams-deliberate-effort-to.html) by Dr. Ezra Chwat provides manuscript evidence that Rambam deliberately adjusted the MT to have this many chapters.

Comment: Interestingly, there are 17 days of learning non-prakim within Rambam cycle: 12 days allocated to the hakdamah and an additional 5 days dedicated to the seder hatefillah, culminating in a total of 1017 days, or 339 days for those who cover 3 chapters daily. It's also worth noting that in various manuscripts of Maimonides' works, there are variations in the total number of prakim mentioned at the end Mishneh Torah.

Answer (score 2):

There are 14 books, I don't know the other statistics.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Lubavitcher Rebbe's [daily Rambam](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/900030/jewish/Studying-Rambam-Daily.htm) program, it's not exactly aligned with the number of chapters because the introduction is included in the cycle. But it'll take about a year to finish three chapters a day or three years to learn one chapter a day.