# Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Statistics

Tags: number

(Answered)

How many Simanim are in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch?

(How many words are in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch?

How many letters are in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch?)

(Not Answered)

How many Sifim are in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: You can answer this question yourself if you go to http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90 and get busy counting.

Comment: it would be easier to just to go on http://www.yonanewman.org/and they have all sifim spelled out easily. But I will leave that up to the people who answer (most probably no one will do it) but a link to the answer would be the best

Comment: Link didn't work for me. I got a 404.

Comment: sorry http://www.yonanewman.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Kitsur:
221 simanim
161102 words
651478 letters
```

Stats from the 1983 Rivad Publications edition. (This is relevant because different editions will have different numbers or words and letters even if they use the same core text because some may expand roshei tevot or do other things like that).