# Number of Se'ifim in Shulchan Aruch

Tags: shulchan-aruch, statistics

How many se'ifim (not simanim) are there in the entire Shulchan Aruch?  Not just Orach Chaim and not the Kitzur, but the entire, unabridged sefer.

I'm trying to figure out scheduling for reviewing large parts of it.

Comment: [Of interest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34248/16706)

Comment: There are some seifim which are much longer than others and some which are tiny. To review based on the number of seifim might be difficult.

Comment: @David Then something like [this](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/36149799/שולחן-ערוך-בכרך-אחד---דף-ליום) may serve you well for your agenda;  SA is divided by total content size to finish in a year (only SA & Rama). Other publications have a similar break-up in four volumes.

Comment: Similar to what @Oliver said, you can just pick up the volume(s) that you intend to study from, divide the total number of pages by the time you want to review it, and you have a schedule! i.e. if your volume has a thousand pages and you want to complete it in a year, 1000/365 (or 354) will mean you've got to do about 3 pages a day. As a bonus, this'll keep the physical number of pages consistent between days regardless of the size of specific Seifim.

Comment: why not use the dovor b'ito. which has all daily learning for everything.

Comment: This is very tempting to take on ,but wonder how long it would take to get the numbers.

Comment: This must be a really Jewish questing considering how each answer is so different from the next....

Comment: The things people will go through to get fake points on a website...

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all their alternatives.  I have experience using these different approaches and they didn't work for various reasons.  Wrt the SA in one volume, I own that and have used it, along with two other of their editions (pocket and four volume), but it is not standard (so if I don't have the sefer I can't do the limud) and the different volumes have different schedules (!) so I can't even use the pocket size for travel and the large one for home use.

Comment: The issue with splitting up the volume(s) is that not everyone has a full set of SA available to use in all places and in order for this to work it needs to be accessible.  I also use my phone a lot for this, which doesn't have the tzuras hadaf.  Additionally, when doing Orach Chaim I use a mishna berura for the limud and with other sefarim I will use the tzuras hadaf. The only alternative seems to be division by se'ifim.

Comment: Division by simanim would also theoretically work, but they seem to vary in size much more than se'ifim.

Comment: @David! I’d love to know what you ended up doing with this info.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Total

There are 13,550 seifim in Shulchan Aruch.

### Breakdown

- Orach Chaim — 4,170
- Yoreh Deiah — 3,700
- Even HaEzer — 1,988
- Choshen Mishpat — 3,692

### Methodology

I looked at the beginning of every siman where it says how many seifim are in that siman. I input all the data into an Excel sheet and let it calculate the totals.

In Orach Chaim the original Venice 1565 edition [had no siman 603](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45227&st=&pgnum=245). The modern edition that I used simply took the second seif from siman 602 and made it its own siman using the number 603. The total number of seifim was not affected by this.

In Yoreh Deiah there were two places where the siman numbers are corrupted. In the original Venice 1565 edition, [169 was skipped](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=89). In the modern edition that I used they simply labeled that siman as 168/169 with 27 seifim. In the original edition [the number 296 was used twice](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=192) (in the modern edition I used it was 297 that was used twice) so they appear as two separate simanim.

There were also (at least) two simanim that had the wrong amount of seifim listed in the title. Siman 234 lists 72 seifim in the title but actually has 74 seifim (both in the [modern edition](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6662) I used as well as in [the original Venice 1565 edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=141).) Siman 340 lists 40 seifim in the title but actually has 39 seifim in [the original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=226). The [modern edition](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6918) corrected the title to list 39 seifim.

In Even HaEzer there were two sections with no siman numbers. Seder HaGet and Seder Chalitza were counted as their own simanim, with 101 and 57 seifim respectively.

Based on the numbers provided by Josh Friedlander in [his answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97264/13438) from Wikisource and Sefaria, I checked every discrepancy against the original Venice 1565 edition. In every instance except one, the Tzuras Hadaf edition that I used had the same number of seifim as the original edition; the Wikisource differed from the original edition in two places; and Sefaria differed from the original in 5 places:

- In O.C. 106 [the original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45227&st=&pgnum=42) has 3 seifim while [the Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%95)
  has 2 (it incorporates seif 2 into seif 1).
- In O.C. 219 [the original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45227&st=&pgnum=86) has 9 seifim while [Tzuras Hadaf](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1049) and [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.219?lang=bi) have 10 seifim (both of them break off the last bit of the last seif into a new seif, yet they both only list 9 seifim).
- In O.C. 601 and 602 [the original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45227&st=&pgnum=245&hilite=) had 2 seifim in each. However, the original edition skipped the number 603 for the next siman (i.e the siman after 602 is 604) so other versions tried to compensate to keep the numbers accurate. The Tzuras Hadaf edition and [the Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%92) simply separated the second seif from 602 and called it siman 603, thus the total number of seifim is unchanged. Sefaria also split off that seif into a siman 603, but for some reason it has the first seif of 602 twice in siman 602, so the total number of seifim becomes off by 1.
- In Y.D. 32 [the original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=16) has 7 seifim while [the Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%91) has 8 seifim (it splits off the last bit of seif 7 into a new seif).
- In C.M. 41 [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.41?lang=bi) duplicates the last seif, so it has 5 seifim instead of 4.
- In C.M. 74 [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.74?lang=bi) duplicates the last seif, so it has 8 seifim instead of 7.
- In C.M. 76 [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.76?lang=bi) duplicates the last seif, so it has 4 seifim instead of 3.

### Limitations

My data is based on the siman titles in the Tzuras Hadaf edition. If there are any mistakes in the siman titles regarding the number of seifim in the siman then my data for that siman will be mistaken.

Additionally, it is possible that I may have made data entry errors, in which case some of the numbers might be incorrect.

However, as per above, I corrected errors by consulting the original edition in any case of discrepancy. So unless there was a case where the Tzuras Hadaf edition, the Wikisource, and Sefaria all differed from the original edition in the same siman with the exact same difference, any errors were presumably caught.

### Data

Here is the data that I entered into the Excel sheet. Anyone can feel free to check it for mistakes and point them out if they find any. (I realize this is rather messy; if anyone has any ideas of how to better present this, please suggest it.)

**O.C.**

```
9
6
17
23
1
4
4
17
6
12
15
3
3
5
6
1
3
3
2
2
4
1
4
6
13
2
11
3
1
5
2
52
5
4
1
3
3
13
10
8
1
3
9
1
2
9
14
1
1
1
9
1
26
3
22
5
2
7
5
5
26
5
9
4
3
10
1
1
2
5
7
5
4
6
6
8
2
1
9
1
2
2
5
1
2
1
3
1
8
27
6
10
4
9
4
2
5
5
3
1
4
5
3
8
1
3
4
12
3
8
3
2
9
9
1
1
5
1
4
1
3
3
6
12
2
4
2
45
2
1
8
2
1
2
14
1
6
1
11
3
8
2
5
4
3
4
8
1
1
5
12
1
22
15
2
1
1
13
20
15
4
10
2
2
2
1
20
17
3
22
5
2
3
8
6
1
5
7
6
5
10
7
12
6
5
2
4
10
2
5
3
2
6
3
3
4
4
1
11
2
4
18
8
13
5
6
1
18
3
2
6
2
3
1
4
14
8
9
9
2
2
4
6
13
10
1
3
3
2
5
1
3
2
2
4
4
1
2
2
17
1
1
2
6
6
5
6
4
4
2
2
7
5
9
3
1
8
1
7
2
4
3
17
10
4
13
3
13
1
2
17
10
7
4
12
5
5
1
7
2
1
7
1
7
7
5
1
10
2
2
6
2
3
5
1
8
5
15
10
1
51
13
27
3
23
14
22
52
5
9
9
10
10
12
13
12
7
19
17
20
19
6
10
15
16
13
4
49
9
11
10
4
3
27
5
13
4
8
7
14
3
1
1
2
19
3
1
1
5
3
1
2
3
2
5
2
3
14
1
3
2
12
36
5
8
15
1
5
1
8
6
19
1
4
4
4
1
5
2
4
7
20
1
2
4
9
1
1
1
2
2
8
3
3
1
2
18
11
11
1
1
1
1
1
9
1
3
4
13
3
1
1
1
2
4
5
1
5
1
2
1
7
4
1
3
4
1
8
2
1
2
2
11
4
1
3
4
2
4
4
2
11
3
8
3
4
12
7
1
7
27
7
9
4
6
3
2
1
6
7
5
7
3
1
3
6
16
10
1
3
3
16
7
1
7
2
2
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
4
3
10
9
2
1
4
3
4
3
17
20
5
6
7
4
2
4
1
9
7
2
7
11
4
3
8
11
9
3
4
9
5
1
3
4
4
2
2
12
24
2
4
1
8
2
5
3
3
4
16
6
14
8
5
2
3
2
11
5
12
20
2
4
18
12
2
25
2
1
1
1
10
5
5
13
1
1
6
8
3
12
2
3
3
3
1
5
13
16
1
1
3
3
4
9
2
4
5
23
3
5
9
9
8
4
2
1
1
1
3
1
1
3
2
1
1
2
1
4
6
4
1
4
2
10
12
4
2
2
4
10
6
1
6
4
6
5
1
3
4
3
19
13
10
4
10
4
1
2
3
2
8
10
1
1
3
2
9
11
2
22
6
2
15
2
2
1
1
1
1
9
1
3
1
3
3
11
2
1
1
2
1
3
8
2
4
2
3
5
4
1
1
2
2
3
1
3
7
3
2
8
6
18
11
4
4
4
4
8
1
```

**Total:** 4170

**Y.D.**

```
14
11
1
7
3
4
1
1
1
3
4
2
6
6
3
12
3
20
8
4
5
2
6
20
3
2
1
24
1
2
4
7
11
10
10
17
7
5
25
6
10
9
6
10
2
6
5
12
5
3
4
7
5
5
13
10
21
12
2
3
33
4
2
21
14
10
6
15
21
6
3
4
6
1
3
6
1
1
3
6
9
5
10
17
3
10
11
2
4
4
8
9
1
9
7
5
3
9
7
4
9
4
7
3
14
2
2
7
2
10
7
16
16
12
3
7
1
13
20
16
7
12
26
27
11
7
4
5
20
10
2
7
7
13
16
1
6
11
15
1
8
15
6
2
9
15
5
12
5
3
14
2
4
2
3
3
3
2
3
23
11
5
3
4
1
3
1
27
2
1
6
19
8
8
8
40
3
19
12
12
6
1
12
4
5
14
6
34
54
1
5
1
14
17
13
5
48
13
1
75
9
7
4
2
5
1
5
1
3
4
1
3
2
6
12
48
6
3
23
14
1
4
1
1
3
3
51
9
1
1
20
1
72
6
6
12
23
17
25
9
36
9
18
22
26
4
8
16
5
14
12
12
2
2
6
11
13
6
1
1
7
5
6
13
14
85
12
11
2
7
4
6
7
6
13
1
4
5
2
5
19
5
2
2
23
2
15
6
1
3
13
5
28
7
69
40
16
2
2
7
15
2
2
1
31
12
3
5
2
3
1
3
7
11
7
6
3
6
4
7
23
5
1
14
2
5
5
3
10
9
146
1
14
48
10
3
1
2
5
39
6
1
2
20
8
1
3
3
4
1
2
4
7
1
1
1
2
3
2
1
5
6
7
7
2
4
6
3
1
1
6
2
9
11
11
4
3
13
5
25
6
5
2
5
3
1
2
2
8
7
3
3
4
6
3
3
2
1
14
2
7
12
10
```

**Total:** 3700

**E.H.**

```
14
11
9
37
14
18
23
5
2
7
8
4
14
1
31
6
58
1
2
2
7
20
7
1
10
4
10
23
10
11
9
4
2
4
15
12
27
39
7
8
4
5
2
12
3
8
4
7
3
7
1
1
3
1
7
4
1
2
4
1
2
13
2
6
4
13
11
10
7
12
4
1
9
12
5
13
5
8
3
18
2
8
2
1
19
2
2
12
4
20
5
8
32
7
7
21
2
7
2
16
4
9
8
6
7
2
10
3
4
2
17
18
10
12
10
6
11
19
11
11
8
2
5
9
23
50
13
7
34
22
9
4
3
10
5
7
5
4
18
11
69
19
23
7
10
5
3
2
7
4
1
12
1
24
101
22
13
10
6
7
8
9
5
8
8
5
9
6
9
56
57
20
10
16
17
7
14
8
5
22
```

**Total:** 1988

**C.M.**

```
6
1
4
1
5
1
12
5
8
4
6
20
7
8
5
5
12
6
3
1
1
3
1
1
5
4
2
26
3
14
4
2
18
35
14
2
22
1
17
2
4
15
29
11
23
38
2
1
10
1
7
2
1
5
2
7
2
5
1
12
16
1
2
1
24
42
38
2
6
6
23
45
20
7
25
3
11
8
14
2
32
13
4
5
7
9
39
33
6
16
9
14
18
9
6
6
30
11
8
3
11
5
11
16
6
3
12
21
6
11
24
5
3
7
6
2
7
4
6
2
12
9
15
1
10
23
2
2
22
7
14
6
7
6
2
2
3
8
4
15
20
3
4
4
7
25
5
2
31
7
3
1
20
32
44
7
13
9
4
3
6
7
6
8
1
1
2
2
2
2
17
9
4
5
63
51
5
3
1
1
3
12
9
2
10
2
4
6
1
18
4
16
1
3
11
5
7
15
4
12
2
15
10
11
12
4
21
1
10
3
7
9
2
13
8
14
7
25
6
18
1
4
5
2
6
6
39
20
2
10
28
23
1
4
28
9
2
3
2
4
12
10
25
1
11
17
5
13
5
26
2
2
33
1
9
4
7
2
9
11
4
21
3
8
1
5
27
5
6
3
5
18
18
1
31
6
15
10
6
12
10
1
3
4
10
5
3
2
5
28
28
22
4
6
3
8
1
2
1
4
10
2
15
6
7
8
7
7
5
3
6
20
4
2
4
3
4
1
1
5
2
2
1
1
1
1
2
2
1
5
3
6
8
4
3
4
20
9
11
8
8
1
2
4
2
19
1
8
5
1
1
1
4
6
3
10
3
12
12
10
8
13
11
9
2
4
6
1
11
7
4
3
3
6
9
1
1
9
4
4
1
1
5
4
2
4
1
16
20
12
12
1
4
6
1
10
2
5
5
4
2
1
3
2
3
5
4
2
4
38
7
5
3
2
3
1
7
18
3
44
14
2
4
11
5
1
10
```

**Total:** 3692

**Grand Total**

13550

Comment: Intresting, I used the Shulchan Aruch in one vol,wonder why we got a diff number

Comment: @sam can you post your Siman by Siman data into your answer like he did here? Then we could easily compare the two

Comment: Yes ,I will do later today,dont have access to it now

Comment: This seems to be the most accurate, since the numbers were provided, but can anyone verify this?  I'm not exactly sure how to choose the correct answer since there are conflicting ones...

Comment: @David You don't have to accept any answer.

Comment: @Alex Would you consider <pre> tags a better presentation? It takes up more vertical space but it allows copying and pasting the data as a list instead of as a block of numbers. I edited it so you can see, but revert it if you see fit (even if you revert, having the list in edit history might help for copying the data)

Comment: @ba After I posted it I started changing it to a vertical list, but I wasn't necessarily convinced that it was better, so i didn't actually save it. It doesn't matter that much to me; whatever is more convenient for people to read is fine. I guess I'll ask people for their opinions in Chat.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for doing this work and for posting your specific counts. I used a script to count and compared mine with yours, found the discrepancies, and double-checked them with my [source](https://bit.ly/2QaXzO4) (WikiSource, see my answer below for more). Here is where my source differs from your count - format is ‘siman (my count, your count)’. OC 35 (1,4) 106 (2,3), 288 (10,102) 312 (10,1) 562 (13,16) YD 32 (8,7) 233 (74,72) EH None CM 390 (12,1) Some of these may be differences between editions, and some look like typos.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander O.C. 35 was a typo. O.C. 106 actually does have 3 (both in the edition I used, and in [the original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45227&st=&pgnum=42)). O.C. 288 was a typo. O.C. 312 was a typo. O.C. 562 was a typo. Y.D. 32 actually does have 7 (both in the edition I used, and in the [original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=16)). Y.D. 233 (for me it's 234, because as mentioned in <cont.>

Comment: <cont.> my answer, 169 was skipped) lists 72 in the title but actually has 74 (both in the edition I used, and in [the original edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=141)). C.M. 390 was a typo. I have corrected the ones that were mistakes, and our totals are now only off by 6. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean to say that after all this I was only 17 off? I am thus impressed on all sides.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel If my analysis is correct. However, the totals are only 17 off but the individual sections vary a lot. In O.C. you have 62 fewer, in Y.D. you have 15 fewer, in E.H. you have 2 fewer, and in C.M. you have 62 more. (But that's partly because you counted a section in C.M. that's not part of the Shulchan Aruch, which gave you an extra 25 seifim.)

Comment: I see. I image my OC so far off is because I entered the numbers in a very unorganized and impressive way, so that they became incorrect on account of entry. But that is neither here nor there. Thanks

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Do you have the data you entered? Then we could compare siman by siman to see where the discrepancies lie.

Comment: Looks like sefaria may have fixed the duplication errors (unless i didn't understand what you were referring to)

Comment: @DoubleAA Looks like it's still an issue. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB7xU.png)'s an image. You can see that it has the same text twice in a row, first labeled as Seif 4 and then as Seif 5.

Answer (score 12):

I believe this would make an enjoyable web-scraping project, which might yield a more easily reproducible (and checkable) result. I've scraped the numbers from WikiSource, and gotten a total for Orach Chaim of **4175** (one away from Sam's answer). The fact that people have gotten such disparate answers implies to me that different editions might count se'ifim differently.

WikiSource is missing se'if numbers for at least some simanim in the other three sections, but I think I can get around this by scraping one level down - isolating the links to individual simanim, crawling each one programmatically and counting the number of headings with the word "סעיף". But it might take me a while. In the meantime, my code is available (in a Jupyter notebook) [here](https://github.com/lordgrenville/shulchan-aruch-count/blob/master/shulchan%20aruch.ipynb). EDIT: Finished, code is on Github.

OC: 4169
YD: 3701
EH: 1988
CM: 3692

**Grand total: 13556**

Using `Double AA`'s recommendation (and code) to count line breaks in Sefaria's repository, I get the following numbers:

OC: 4172
YD: 3712
EH: 1988
CM: 3695

**Grand total: 13597**

By comparing the simanim with discrepancies one by one, the following emerged:

In OC 106 and 219, Sefaria splits seifim in a way that WikiSource does not, not in line with the traditional split. Siman 602 erroneously *duplicates a siman*. That also happens in CM 41, 74 and 76. Thus, I believe the counts of **OC 4169/4171** and **CM 3692** most accurate.

On EH, the counts concur on **1988** seifim.

On YD, the method I used to parse Sefaria's raw text made some mistakes which don't appear in Sefaria's text itself. I believe the most accurate answer is **3701 seifim**.

Thanks to `Alex` for valuable feedback.

A table with my count and that of Sefaria is found here:
[OC](https://github.com/lordgrenville/shulchan-aruch-count/blob/master/OC.csv), [YD](https://github.com/lordgrenville/shulchan-aruch-count/blob/master/YD.csv), [EH](https://github.com/lordgrenville/shulchan-aruch-count/blob/master/EH.csv), [CM](https://github.com/lordgrenville/shulchan-aruch-count/blob/master/CM.csv)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to work with Sefaria's data? https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export/blob/master/txt/Halakhah/Shulchan%20Arukh/Shulchan%20Arukh%2C%20Orach%20Chayim/Hebrew/merged.txt and then just count line breaks.

Comment: Something like `sum([1 for __ in [_ for _ in merged.split('\n')[merged.split('\n').index('Siman 1'):] if _] if 'Siman ' not in __])` where "merged" is the entire merged.txt read in as one string like `open("merged.txt", "r")`

Comment: I've added a comparison to Sefaria in my answer, and in the repository. Thanks!

Comment: Can you identify which Simanim are different between Sefaria and wikisource?

Comment: I did in the code on Github, though it's a bit messy, and I've uploaded links to a table you can look at. From some sample testing it seems like Sefaria is pretty accurate, and WikiSource has some mistakes.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I checked all the Yoreh Deiah discrepancies. In every case except one, the Wikisource count accorded with the original edition:

Comment: [Y.D. 94](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=48) ,[Y.D. 113](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=57), [Y.D. 139](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=76), [Y.D. 151](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=82), [Y.D. 189](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=102) The only exception was [Y.D. 340](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=226) which has 39 seifim but 40 listed. Wikisource has the former, Sefaria has the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I missed [Y.D. 185](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=99), [Y.D. 240](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=150) and [Y.D. 297](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=192) where Wikisource also matches the original edition.

Comment: But the sum of the seifim for Sefaria in the table is only 3,712.

Comment: Are you sure the code you used for Sefaria is entirely accurate? I checked some of the discrepancies on Sefaria and they all actually had the same number of seifim as the Wikisource.

Comment: I finished checking all the discrepancies. Only 7 of the cases where your Sefaria results showed a different number from the Wikisource results were actual discrepancies (as documented in my answer).

Answer (score 10):

So I decided to try counting for Orach Chaim ,and surprisingly did not take long at all (one hour around). I used excel to calculate the sum of all the seifim in all the simanim.

Orach Chaim = 697 simanim which has a total of 4174 seifim. The avg amount is 6.04 seifeim in a siman. The max is 52 and min is 1.

The other 3 are a work in progress.

Comment: Hope to have the rest in the near future.

Comment: +1 for the amount of time devoted. (I’m surprised no expert code-writers here @ MY came up with a compete answer within minutes.)

Comment: Good point ,I am no expert did old fashioned way

Comment: For example, look at [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2677) beauty by Shalom.

Comment: My main motivation to even bother with this ,is to the best of my knowledge this data does not exist,and it should

Comment: @sam Cool, looks like we had the same idea. But the results are slightly different.

Answer (score 7):

**TOTAL: 13,533**

Orach Chaim (697 chapters): 4,108

Yoreh Deah (403 chapters): 3,685

Even HaEzer (178 chapters): 1,986

Choshen Mishpat (427 chapters): 3,754

I used the [Shulchan Aruch in one volume](https://www.judaicaplace.com/shulchan-aruch-yomi-1-volume-hardcover/sady1/) mentioned in a comment by Oliver and counted the seifim. I scanned the page (optically) and mentally added as I turned the pages. Usually when I got to a high enough number and I didn't want to lose the count, I wrote the number down. Occasionally I stopped to read an interesting siman.

When I had one section completed I pasted that number [here](https://www.miniwebtool.com/sum-calculator/) to get the sum.

Still, I don't know why you would want to set up a study system like this when there are things like the volume mentioned above which even includes the 'Beis Yosef's 30 day review schedule'. Nonetheless, for fun these are the numbers you'd have to complete in an example review system (in approximation):

6 Months: 75.18 per day

1 Year: 37.59 per day

1 Month: 451.1 per day

8 Months: 56.38 per day

---

Notes:

During the count I noticed some very big simanim (in terms of seif count). So, for trivia, chapter 331 in YoreH Deah has 146 seifim, the most in Shulchan Aruch.

Second place is in Ever Haezer, the nameless siman between 154 and 155 (i.e. Seder HaGet) has 101.

In Choshen Mishpat there is a another numberless siman between 25 and 26 (and Even Haezer between 169-170), all of which were included in this count.

My counts may contain human error; but it'll get you to where you need to go.

Comment: (In your concluding sentence I -understandably- read: “My counts may contain humor”) My my, the discrepancies between all these answers...